# .Net WebApi concurrent constructor initialization from different controller methods

Tags: c#, .net, oop, trace, webapi

Let's say I have this .NET WebApi controller "SampleController"

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    public string SampleAPIMethod1()
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass("sampleParam1", "sampleParam2");

        bool success = tc.TestFunction();

        //some logic
    }

    public string SampleAPIMethod2()
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass("sampleParam1", "sampleParam2");

        bool success = tc.TestFunction();

        //some different logic
    }
}
```

And this utility class "TestClass"

```
public class TestClass
{
    //other out of scope properties

    Stream myFile;
    TextWriterTraceListener myTextListener;

    public TestClass(string inParam1, string inParam2) {
        string newGuidStr = Guid.NewGuid.ToString();
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();

        myFile = File.Create("c:\logs\" + newGuidStr + ".txt");
        myTextListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(myFile);
        Trace.Listener.Add(myTextListener);

        Trace.WriteLine("Current UTC Time: " & DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() & " - Called from: " & st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
    }

    public bool TestFunction()
    {       
        try
        {           
            Trace.WriteLine("1");
            //some logic
            Trace.WriteLine("2");
            //some further logic
            Trace.WriteLine("3");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //some error handling
        }
        finally
        {
            Trace.Flush();
            myFile.Close();
        }
    }       
}
```

How can a file with the same name (as defined by the newGuidStr variable which is always re-instantiated within the TestClass() constructor) contain trace logs that indicate instantiation from both SampleAPIMethod1 and SampleAPIMethod2? The issue happens when concurrent multiple requests are sent from a client app to the .NET WebApi. In my opinion, this should never be the case, as the 'tc' object within SampleAPIMethod1 and SampleAPIMethod2 is re-initialized and re-instantiated upon every new request and the 2 different API methods should be totally independent. This even happened by multiple requests on the same API method. That 2 different instances created the same GUID file name is highly unlikely, and that it happened to me multiple times makes it more so.

Text file output in the same file: 5a483a4f-4d5f-4135-8f5a-8eb840a433ed.txt

- Current UTC Time: 29/03/2020 16:15:44 - Called from: SampleAPIMethod1
- Current UTC Time: 29/03/2020 16:15:44 - 1
- Current UTC Time: 29/03/2020 16:15:44 - 2
- Current UTC Time: 29/03/2020 16:15:46 - Called from: SampleAPIMethod2
- Current UTC Time: 29/03/2020 16:15:46 - 1
- Current UTC Time: 29/03/2020 16:15:46 - 2
- Current UTC Time: 29/03/2020 16:15:46 - 3
- Current UTC Time: 29/03/2020 16:15:46 - 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that even though you create a new trace listener for each request, you then put them in a global collection of listeners in the form of `Trace.Listeners`, which is shared between all requests. Calling `Trace.WriteLine` will write the given message to *all* listeners in this collection, and thus if a new request comes in before the old listener is deactivated (i.e. the file it writes to is closed), both listeners will get calls to log the same message.

To fix this, the `TestClass` object should call `WriteLine` on its own `myTextListener` object directly, instead of using the global `Trace` object. This ensures the message will only ever be written to the listener specific to that `TestClass` instance. This also means you no longer have to add the trace listeners to the `Trace.Listeners` collection.

I have modified your `TestClass` example to implement this, using comments to annotate changes:

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    //other out of scope properties

    Stream myFile;
    TextWriterTraceListener myTextListener;

    public TestClass(string inParam1, string inParam2) {
        string newGuidStr = Guid.NewGuid.ToString();
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();

        myFile = File.Create("c:\\logs\\" + newGuidStr + ".txt");
        myTextListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(myFile);
        // Removed `Trace.Listeners.Add(myTextListener)`

        myTextListener.WriteLine("Current UTC Time: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + " - Called from: " + st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
    }

    public bool TestFunction()
    {       
        try
        {
            // Changed `Trace` to `myTextListener` here
            myTextListener.WriteLine("1");
            myTextListener.WriteLine("2");
            myTextListener.WriteLine("3");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            // Changed `Trace` to `myTextListener` here
            myTextListener.Flush();
            myFile.Close();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I am not entirely sure I understand the changes required, though. Should I not add the listener to the collection? Should the declarations happen elsewhere? Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri I have updated my answer to maybe provide a better explanation, and added example code for the changes to the `TestClass` class.

Comment: ok was close to understanding but your example definitely helped! I will try that and let you know :)